# I wrote this code and got "Could not find installable ISAM" error while running my page

Tags: c#

```
public partial class CountryMaster : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=MicroSoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Souce=G:\WebDesign\WebGridView\WebGridView\Database\PracticeDataBase.accdb");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    int MaxVal()
    {
        int max = 0;
        OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand("Select max(CountryId) from CountryMaster", conn);
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            conn.Open();
        OleDbDataReader rd = comm.ExecuteReader();
        if (rd.HasRows)
            while (rd.Read())
                int.TryParse(rd[0].ToString(), out max);
        max++;
        comm.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
        return max;
    }


    protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand("Insert into CountryMaster(CountryId,CountryName) Values(" + MaxVal() + ",'" + txtname.Text + "')", conn);
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            conn.Open();
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        comm.Dispose();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is ACE installed on the server?  If not you can download it from here, http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891&displaylang=en

Comment: Which version of AccessDatabaseEngine (64/32bit) have you installed? (If 64bit then apps need to be 64bit)

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 64 bit version.